# PHPExcel how to get data from cells and add to database

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Im trying to get data from a excel file with multiple sheets and add that data to a mysql database. Here is where im stuck :

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() .PATH_SEPARATOR .'modules/phpexcel/Classes/');

include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $target_dir = 'uploads/';
    $target_file = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

    $inputFileType = 'Excel5';

    $inputFileName = 'uploads/PIE_Date.xls';

    class chunkReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter{
        private $_startRow = 0;
        private $_endRow = 0;

        public function setRows($startRow, $chunkSize){
            $this->_startRow = $startRow;
            $this->_endRow = $startRow + $chunkSize;
        }

        public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = ''){
            if(($row == 1) || ($row >= $this->_startRow && $row < $this->_endRow)){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

    $chunkSize = 2048;

    $chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter();

    $objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);

    for($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 65536; $startRow += $chunkSize){
        $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow, $chunkSize);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);


    }

}
```

From here I don't know how to get data from cells. If I can get data from cell I think I can handle the rest of the code(adding it to database).

Comment: [PHPExcel Documentation on looping through the rows and cells of a worksheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#looping-through-cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']) && $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'] != "") {

    $allowedExtensions = array("xls", "xlsx");

    // Returns the extension of the file
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (in_array($ext, $allowedExtensions)) {
        $file = "uploads/".$_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
        $isUploaded = copy($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $file);
        if ($isUploaded) {
            include 'dbconnect.php'; //Connection file
            include "Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";

            try{
                $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
            } catch(Exception $e){
                die('Erroe loading File "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME).'" '.$e->getMessge() );
            }

            // An ecel file may contains many sheets so you have to specify which one you need to read or work with
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);

            // It returns the highest number of rows
            $total_rows = $sheet->getHighestRow();

            // It returns the highest number of columns
            $highest_column = $sheet->getHighestColumn();


            // Table used to display the contents of the file
            echo '<h4>Data from excel file</h4>';
            echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="responsive">';

            // Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
            for ($row=2; $row <=$total_rows; $row++) { 
                // Read a row of data into an rray
                $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highest_column . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

                $sql = "write your sql query here";

                if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                    // if success show the excel table
                    echo "<tr>";
                    foreach($rowData[0] as $key=>$value) {
                        echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";

                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);

                }

            } //end for
            echo '</table>';

        } //end 
        else{
            echo '<span class="msg">File not uploaded!</span>';
        }
    } // end if (in_array($ext, $allowedExtensions)) 
    else {
    echo '<span class="msg">This type of file not allowed!</span>';
    }


} // end if (isset($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']) && $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'] != "")
else {
echo '<span class="msg">Select an excel file first!</span>';
}
```

Hope this will help you.